# how to pass dynamic mail id(like mail DL or groups of mails) to email notification in jenkins pipeline shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How can we pass dynamic mail id to mail notification in jenkins pipeline shared library by using groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

You can call "emailext" function :

```
my_email = 'someone@somewhere.org' // dynamic assign
emailext body: 'My Body', subject: 'My Subject', to: "$my_email"
```

Regards

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responce. Actually the Input parameter will be email DL or email list (Email list will be a variable in Jenkinsfile). for this, above solution will work?

Comment: @Sunil, see [emailext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin). This one support comma or white space separated addresses. Distribution list are _(in Outlook/Exchange)_ set with a kind of "internal" email address. You can use this kind of technical email address for DL.